# extract <label><span> tag on html with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I would like to extract webpage like:
`https://www.glassdoor.com/Overview/Working-at-Apple-EI_IE1138.11,16.htm`,so I would like to return the result as the following format.

```
Website       Headquarters  Size             Revenue                Type
www.apple.com Cupertino, CA 10000+ employees $10+ billion (USD) per year     Company - Public (AAPL)
```

I then use the following code with `beatifulsoup` to get this.

```
all_href = com_soup.find_all('span', {'class': re.compile('value')})
all_href = list(set(all_href))
```

It returns tag with `<span>`. Also, it didn't show tag under `<label>`

```
[<span class="value"> Computer Hardware &amp; Software</span>,
 <span class="value"> Company - Public (AAPL) </span>,
 <span class="value">10000+ employees</span>,
 <span class="value"> $10+ billion (USD) per year</span>,
 <span class="value-title" title="4.0"></span>,
 <span class="value">Cupertino, CA</span>,
 <span class="value"> 1976</span>,
 <span class="value-title" title="5.0"></span>,
 <span class="value website"><a class="link" href="http://www.apple.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">www.apple.com</a></span>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your beautifulsoup pull is too specific. You're catching all the "span" tags, where the class = value.

When you look at the HTML, you can find that section quickly by searching for the text of some of the fields. What you should do is get everything inside any of the div tags where class = 'infoEntity', which contains all 7 fields you're interested in grabbing from that "Overview" section.

Within that, there is a label tag for each field, which has attributes correlating to the labels you want above, and that are in that Overview section.

So, start with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
<div class="eep-pill"><p class="tightVert h2 white"><strong>Enhanced</strong> Profile&nbsp;<span class="round ib"><i class="icon-star-white"></i></span></p></div></header><section class="center flex-grid padVertLg eepModal"><h2>Try Enhanced Profile Free for a Month</h2><p>Explore the many benefits of having a premium branded profile on Glassdoor, like increased influence and advanced analytics.</p><div class="margBot"><i class="feaIllustration"></i></div><a href='/employers/enhanced/landing_input.htm?src=info_mod' class='gd-btn gd-btn-link gradient gd-btn-1 gd-btn-med span-1-2'><span>Get Started</span><i class='hlpr'></i></a><p>Changes wont be saved until you sign up for an Enhanced Profile subscription.</p></section></div></article><article id='MainCol'><div id='EmpBasicInfo' class='module empBasicInfo ' data-emp-id='1138'><div class=''><header class='tbl fill '><h2 class='cell middle tightVert blockMob'> Apple Overview</h2></header><div class='info flexbox row col-hh'><div class='infoEntity'><label>Website</label><span class='value website'><a class="link" href="http://www.apple.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer">www.apple.com</a></span></div><div class='infoEntity'><label>Headquarters</label><span class='value'>Cupertino, CA</span></div><div class='infoEntity'><label>Size</label><span class='value'>10000+ employees</span></div><div class='infoEntity'><label>Founded</label><span class='value'> 1976</span></div><div class='infoEntity'><label>Type</label><span class='value'> Company - Public (AAPL) </span></div><div class='infoEntity'><label>Industry</label><span class='value'> Computer Hardware & Software</span></div><div class='infoEntity'><label>Revenue</label><span class='value'> $10+ billion (USD) per year</span></div></div></div><div class=''><div data-full="We&amp;rsquo;re a diverse collection of thinkers and doers, continually reimagining what&amp;rsquo;s possible to help us all do what we love in new ways. The people who work here have reinvented entire industries with the Mac, iPhone, iPad, and Apple Watch, as well as with services, including iTunes, the App Store, Apple Music, and Apple Pay. And the same passion for innovation that goes into our products also applies to our practices &amp;mdash; strengthening our commitment to leave the world better than we found it." class='margTop empDescription'> We&rsquo;re a diverse collection of thinkers and doers, continually reimagining what&rsquo;s possible to help us all do what we love in new ways. The people who work here have reinvented entire industries with the Mac, iPhone, iPad, and Apple Watch, as well as with ... <span class='link minor moreLink' id='ExpandDesc'>Read more</span></div><div class='hr'><hr/></div><h3 class='margTop'>Glassdoor Awards</h3>
"""
items = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
get_info = iter(soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "infoEntity"}))
for item in get_info:
    label = item.find("label")
    value = item.find("span")
    items.append((label.string, value.string))
```

With that, you get a list of tuples in items, that prints out as:

```
[('Website', 'www.apple.com'), ('Headquarters', 'Cupertino, CA'), ('Size', '10000+ employees'), ('Founded', ' 1976'), ('Type', ' Company - Public (AAPL) '), ('Industry', ' Computer Hardware & Software'), ('Revenue', ' $10+ billion (USD) per year')]
```

From there, you can print out that list in any format you like.

Comment: I know what's wrong with my code to extract dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I notice in https://www.glassdoor.com/Overview/Working-at-Apple-EI_IE1138.11,16.htm

You should find the `<div class="infoEntity">` instead of `<span class="value">` so as to get what you want.

```
all_href = com_soup.find_all('div', {'class': re.compile('infoEntity')}).find_all(['span','label'])
all_href = list(set(all_href))
```

It will returns you all `<span>` and `<label>` you want.

What if you want to have `<span>` and `<label>` come together, than change it to

```
all_href = [x.decode_contents(formatter="html") for x in com_soup.find_all('div', {'class': re.compile('infoEntity')})]
#or
all_href = [[x.find('span'), x.find('label')] for x in com_soup.find_all('div', {'class': re.compile('infoEntity')})]
```